# How do we find the condition?

Tags: numerical-analysis, stability, cfl

Suppose that we are given a  numerical scheme.

In order to find the CFL condition , we set $U_j^n= \lambda ^ne^{ik x_j}$ and put it into the numerical scheme.

I have shown that the given method is unstable since $|\lambda|>1$.

In this case, how do we calculate the CFL condition?

I get $| \lambda |= \sqrt{1+\gamma^2 \nu^2 \sin^2{(kh)}}$. This can't be $<1$. What do we do in this case?

The given equation is $u_t+ \gamma u_x=0, \gamma>0$. We know that $k \in \mathbb{R}, \nu=\frac{\tau}{h}$ where $\tau$ is the step of the discretization of time.

[image]

**EDIT**: Also suppose that we have a numerical scheme , put into it $U_j^n= \lambda^n e^{ik x_j}$ and get $a_i^n \nu \leq 1$. Can we then say that the method is stable if and only if $a_i^n \nu \leq 1$ ?

Comment: choose |\lambda|<1?

Comment: I get $| \lambda |= \sqrt{1+\gamma^2 \nu^2 \sin^2{(kh)}}$. This can't be <1. What do we do in this case? $$$$
The given equation is $u_t+ \gamma u_x=0, \gamma>0, x \in \mathbb{R}, t \in [0,T_f]$. @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: Add those details to your question

Comment: also add what is $\nu$ and $k$

Comment: $\nu=\frac{\tau}{h}, k \in \mathbb{R}$. @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: did you read the comment of nicoguaro?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I edited my post...

Comment: @nicoguaro I edited my post...

Comment: You give us the pde but we need its discretized version to determine numerical stability. We cant guess at this because there are too many options to consider; explicit/implicit, upwind/central differencing. we need those details to give you an answer.

Comment: @nluigi I added it.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: OK, so you assert that for your scheme to be stable you need $|\lambda|\leq 1$, however you find that all values for $c=\gamma\nu$ will give $|\lambda| > 1$. What can you conclude?

Comment: @nluigi Do we deduce that the method is unstable?

Comment: exactly! The central differencing scheme you use is known to be unstable. You may want to try upwind differencing: $$\frac{u_i^{n+1}-u_i^n}{\Delta t}=\gamma\frac{u_{i+1}^n-u_i^n}{\Delta x}$$ or some form of implicit methods.

Comment: @nluigi Could you take a look at my question? http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21563/domain-of-dependance

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Could you take a look at my question? http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21563/domain-of-dependance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assert that for your scheme to be stable you need $|λ|≤1$ which is correct, however you find that all values for $c=γν$ will give $|λ|>1$. This means that the discretization you have applied is unstable and there is no CFL condition for stability. Consider using upwind differencing or an implicit method.